# How to do flame reflection on a wall?

Tags: texturing, lighting

How can I light up this wall as if reflections from a fire? sort of a dancing light on the wall? I tried with an emission surface with a wave texture and colour ramp. but it doesn't seem to work. Any other suggestions? enter image description here

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to emit flames onto the wall, animate the flame texture and mix it into the wall material.

[image: animated flames]

Here I animated the z-location of the mapping node to "move" the wave texture and then multiplied it with the wallpaper colour.

[image: node tree]

Note that from 2.81, or daily builds until then, some of the [texture nodes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/User:OmarSquircleArt/GSoC2019/Final_User_Report) now have a time factor so we can properly animate the textures instead of moving through them using the mapping node.